# SplashScreen reopens the application on clicking QuitButton after sleep mode. (Xamarin.Forms - Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen, exit

Xamarin.Forms.Android application reopens itself on clicking the QuitButton after sleep mode.
(The issue is not happening when I remove the SplashScreen).

I tried few methods. This is one of the methods which worked but not as expected.

`((Activity)Forms.Context).FinishAffinity(); JavaSystem.Exit(0);`

This code makes the emulator goes into blank screen.(without closing the application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below to close your application.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

I created a button and tried it. It worked well on my side.

**Update**

This issue might be caused by the reloading from the sleep mode. The android uses the splash screen as a reloading interface. So it will reload when you awaken the phone from the sleep mode.

Comment: Hi Gaungyu Bai, this code works fine for closing the app. But after the sleep mode, if I click on Quit button it reopens the application. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: I think that it does not reopen the application, it might be a reload when you awaken the phone from the sleep mode. The android uses the splash screen as a reloading interface. So you can remove the splash screen, or you can make it transparent.